# How can I recover from corrupted node_modules after attempts to fix a merge conflict?

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, git-merge

I'm a retired developer working on a React hobby project. My code is now in a state that is corrupted by my attempts to resolve a merge conflict between my local master and develop branches. The local develop branch is far ahead of the local master and was working correctly when I attempted to merge it into the master branch. I was shown conflicts in the project.json and yarn.lock files. I tried a few things found from Google searches, but could not resolve it. I aborted the merge, but now the develop branch won't run. I start it with the "react-scripts start" command and it displays my startup splash screen but fails with this error:

```
Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: t(...).isPlaceholder is not a function
```

I'm thinking I can delete node_modules and yarn.lock, copy in the project.json file from my last backup, and then run yarn install to recover. Will this work?

Comment: You can safely delete node_modules, and even the lock files. Will this work? Most likely, give it go, you can't lose anything of importance.

Comment: @tjuugg Thanks, I'll try it now and report back.

Comment: @tjugg That worked. Yarn seemed to stall during the install, sitting still for hours. It worked when I switched to npm install. But now I have a package-lock.json instead of a yarn.lock, Will that cause conflicts if I use yarn to handle my project.json changes from now on? Should I delete it and let yarn create its own lock file later?

Comment: @tjugg Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1):

No problem if you delete your node modules folder and again install npm will get node modules folder with the dependencies which you have in package.json file

Answer (score 0):

The best way in 2021 is to `rm -r ./node_modules`. You can use `yarn check --integrity` to see if there is any need to, it will check everything, even non-js files to see if they are corrupt.

`yarn install --check-files` does not fix corrupt dependencies, it only checks to make sure they are there, not if they've been modified... as you might do if an upstream dependency has a blocking bug and the maintainer is taking a while to fix it.